# Flutter windows: build process failed: \Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, flutter-windows

I have been using flutter windows successfully to run my app. However, recently I downloaded Android Studio and all of a sudden my flutter windows didn't work. It threw out error as following:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\Users\Schwar
tzLab\PycharmProjects\bahavior_rig\behavior_gui\build\windows\CMakeFiles\3a7123e8b5d134f8b6f9d9b7be4b7e62\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\SchwartzLab\PycharmProjects\baha
vior_rig\behavior_gui\build\windows\CMakeFiles\350a25350ac520c3b2e8372c37f12801\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\Users\SchwartzLab\PycharmProjects\bahavior_ri
g\behavior_gui\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...
Exception: Build process failed.
```

I uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 and flutter. However the error persisted.

This is the flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.3.0-16.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1621], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.3.0-16.0.pre at C:\Users\SchwartzLab\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fa5883b78e (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-21 13:04:03 -0700
    • Engine revision 2f067fc4c5
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-136.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\SchwartzLab\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\SchwartzLab\anaconda3\envs\bahavior_rig_\Library\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+8-b765.1)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.2)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.10.31410.357
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\SchwartzLab\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Windows (desktop)       • windows • windows-x64     • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1621]
    • Windows (UWP) (desktop) • winuwp  • windows-uwp-x64 • 
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome  • web-javascript  • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.101
    • Edge (web)              • edge    • web-javascript  • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.68

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

The same app builds on another laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Never met this issue. I'm using the stable channel.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1052], locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[✓] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Try to switch `Channel dev` to `Channel stable`.